# mysql timestamp array to javascript date array using php and json

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Hi there I am building a system that collect data. I store the data in mysql database and display it using amCharts. I making archive chart that displays change in the data over time. I have problems with conversion between mysql timestamp array and javascript date array using php and josn.

The mysql query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP( data ) AS data,ROUND(AVG(CurrentA),3),ROUND(AVG(CurrentB),3),ROUND(AVG(CurrentC),3)
FROM
    Danni
WHERE 
    data 
    BETWEEN 
        '2013-07-13 00:00:00' 
    AND 
        '2013-07-16 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY
    FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data)/72)
LIMIT 40
```

The returned data is formated by this php code:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ustroistvo)){
    $data['date'][] = $row['0'];
    $data['CurrentA'][] = $row['1'];
    $data['CurrentB'][] = $row['2'];
    $data['CurrentC'][] = $row['3'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

So the end result is

```
{"date":["1373748170","1373748192","1373748264","1373748336","1373748408","1373748480","1373748553","1373748624","1373748696","1373796506","1373796577","1373796648","1373796720","1373796792","1373796864","1373796936","1373797008"],"CurrentA":["45.667","37.794","37.508","35.815","31.238","33.061","32.937","35.385","36.020","31.852","34.047","34.508","30.672","37.292","32.554","39.262","32.314"],"CurrentB":["39.000","36.921","33.769","35.123","36.492","41.576","42.492","34.862","36.041","34.967","37.062","33.108","35.531","34.262","33.385","35.877","35.941"],"CurrentC":["35.000","32.429","35.862","36.785","34.873","36.894","31.921","36.938","33.714","40.541","28.688","34.308","33.266","39.846","35.708","34.908","32.118"]}
```

So to convert the date object to actual javascript date I use:

```
success: function (data) {
  console.log(data.date);
  data.date=new Date(data.date*1000);
  console.log(data.date);
  chart.dataProvider=data;
  chart.validateData();
}
```

The problem lies here `data.date=new Date(data.date*1000)` gives me invalid date and I think it is because `data.date` is array. I do not know how to format it properly so that `data.date=new Date(data.date*1000)` returns date array.

Comment: Since its a array, which has set of data, may be you need to make that calculation(data.date*1000) for each data in array.this can be achieved by looping around array until there are no more items in it.

Comment: Well that is the thing I am thinking of but I do not know how to do. :D

Comment: That shouldnt be any different from the regular js looping clause.`var len=data.date.length;for(var i=0;i<len;i++){ var dt=data.date[0];  //now do your processing with every single data here }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
 data.date = data.date.map(function(d) { return new Date(d * 1000) })
```

Also, it's common to write array names in plural, to improve readability and avoid extra confusion. Rename the `date` field to `dates`.

Comment: Thank you this code does The thing i've been searching for. The was written for other part of the website and now I am modifying it for the archives part that is the reason 'date' is not 'dates'.